# Rename Multiple file on using .cmd or .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I have directory which contain no. of file like this

```
abac_273#jj.txt ,
hhh.78448#kkpp.txt ,
dgfhf@ytyt#llltyui.txt
```

I need to write batch script where I need to rename those file like this

```
jj.txt ,   kkpp.txt,   llltyui.txt
```

In simple words, I need to find out # from end and return string after # as output.

Can you please help me out to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=#" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "*#*"') do echo(ren "%%a#%%b" "%%b"
```

should provide what you want - reduce each `%%` to `%` if you execute this from the prompt instead of as a batch line.

If it works correctly for you, change the `echo(ren` to `ren` to actually do the change - this code will simply report the proposed change to the screen.

Comment: Thanks Magoo...just I want to know why use /a-d in dir  command

Comment: `/b` lists in basic form - no header, no summary, just names. `/a-d` suppresses the listing of directorynames.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper, if you open up a cmd prompt you can read the documentation for a cmd by typing the cmd name followed by a /?. example: `dir /?`